# Issue while importing LoginManager from flask.ext.login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying get hands-on with flask-login extension. I am using virtualenv for flask.

I could able to import LoginManager from flask.ext.login in the python interpreter window, but not in the script. Below the import calls in the script.

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
```

I am getting below trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "practice/flask_login.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
File "/Users/sunil/co_operative/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 81, in load_module
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb.tb_next)  
File "/Users/sunil/co_operative/practice/flask_login.py", line 1, in <module>    
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
ImportError: cannot import name LoginManager
```

Answer (score 3):

**Cause of problem :**

Your file name is causing problem.

**Explanation:**

As mentioned in official flask document:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensiondev/, when user try to import flask extension using 
expression import ***flask.ext.something***, flask will look for module ***flask_something***.

So, import flask.ext.login look for module flask_login which is conflicting by your file name. And flask is trying to find Definition of LoginManager in your file.

**Solution**

File rename will solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have called your script `flask_login.py`. When you import from `flask.ext.SOMETHING`, behind the scenes it imports from `flask_SOMETHING`. You are hiding the real `flask_login.py`. Rename your script and you should be good to go.